# Accessing variables from other tab in notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

[image: Tab1 and Tab2 of the notebook]

Hi all,
I was unsuccessful with my last question in this group because my code was too long.
I have now brought my code to a minimum and added a screenshot. I hope this time everything is clear and not confusing.
My question is: how can I check the variable "val" in Tab1 whether it is smaller than 5.
If not, the frame and button in Tab1 must be gray and disabled. The button must not do anything.
The problem is that I have defined "val" as global, but it still brings the error message that "val" is unknown.
Any idea why "val" is not known in Tab1?

```
# Filename: Tab1.py
from tkinter import *

def gen_t1(frame):
    global val
  
    f = LabelFrame(frame, text='f', bg='lightgreen')
    f.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    b1 = Button(f, text='B1').pack()

##    if val < 5:
##        f_enabled = 'disabled'
##        f['bg'] = 'lightgray'
##    else:
##        f_enabled = 'normal'
##        f['bg'] = 'lightgreen'

# Filename: Tab2.py
from tkinter import *

def gen_t2(frame):
    def getValue(event):
        global val
        val = ent.get()
        print(val)

    lbl = Label(frame, text='Val').pack()

    ent = Entry(frame)
    ent.pack()
    ent.insert(0, '2')
  
    ent.bind('<Return>', getValue)

# Filename: TabTop
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

from Tab1 import gen_t1
from Tab2 import gen_t2

firstTime1 = 1
firstTime2 = 1
root = Tk()
root.title('Tab-Tester')
root.geometry('300x200')

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab1 = Frame(nb)
tab2 = Frame(nb)
  
nb.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
nb.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
nb.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

def on_tab_change(event):
    global firstTime1, firstTime2
  
    tab = event.widget.tab('current','text')
    if tab == 'Tab 1':
        print('Tab 1')
        if firstTime1 == 1:
            gen_t1(tab1)
            firstTime1 = 0
    elif tab == 'Tab 2':
        print('Tab 2')
        if firstTime2 == 1:
            gen_t2(tab2)
            firstTime2 = 0
nb.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', on_tab_change)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the object-oriented way to build your GUI. From what I understood of your situation, here's my suggested solution:

### Tab1.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Button_page(ttk.Frame):
    """This will contain what is going to be shown on the first tab."""

    def __init__(self, variable_to_check, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.variable_to_check = variable_to_check
        self.variable_to_check.trace('w', lambda *args: self.update_background())

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.internal_style = ttk.Style()
        self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe', background='lightgreen')
        self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe.Label', background='lightgreen')

        self.f = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='f', style='Tab1.TLabelframe')
        self.f.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
        self.f.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.f.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

        self.b1 = ttk.Button(self.f, text='B1')
        self.b1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N,))

    def update_background(self):
        new_value_string = self.variable_to_check.get()
        try:
            new_value = int(new_value_string)
        except (ValueError):
            new_value = 0

        if new_value < 5:
            self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe', background='lightgray')
            self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe.Label', background='lightgray')
            self.b1.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        else:
            self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe', background='lightgreen')
            self.internal_style.configure('Tab1.TLabelframe.Label', background='lightgreen')
            self.b1.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
```

### Tab2.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Entry_page(ttk.Frame):
    """This will contain what is going to be shown on the second tab."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.entry_value = tk.StringVar()

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=0)

        value_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Val')
        value_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

        value_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entry_value)
        value_entry.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

### TabTop.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import Tab1
import Tab2

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Tab-Tester')
root.geometry('300x200')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
t2 = Tab2.Entry_page(nb)
t1 = Tab1.Button_page(variable_to_check=t2.entry_value, master=nb)
t2.entry_value.set(2)

nb.add(t1, text='Tab 1')
nb.add(t2, text='Tab 2')
nb.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
nb.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
nb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

To synchronize the information between the two tabs, you need a [tkinter variable](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111232933/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) instance that you connect between the `ttk.Entry` and a callback function that will be triggered when the content of the `ttk.Entry`'s is changed.

I know there's not a lot of documentation on `tkinter`. I would recommend :

- https://tkdocs.com/index.html
- Another site that used to have some more information but the site is not accessible at to moment (https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) so you would have to go the Internet Archive Wayback Machine [copy from November 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) so see its information.

---

We could go even more object-oriented:

### TabTop2.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import Tab1
import Tab2

class Tab_pages_application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, size, value_page, action_page, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(size)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        t2 = value_page(nb)
        t1 = action_page(variable_to_check=t2.entry_value, master=nb)
        t2.entry_value.set(2)

        nb.add(t1, text='Tab 1')
        nb.add(t2, text='Tab 2')
        nb.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
        nb.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        nb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tab_pages_application('Tab-Tester', '300x200', Tab2.Entry_page, Tab1.Button_page)
    root.mainloop()
```

Is that what your tried to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me this nice solution. I ran it and I get what I wanted. Because I'm not so familiar with OOP, I try to understand your code and modify it to my needs.I hope you would answer my questions later when I got stuck.
Best Regards
Mohsen

Comment: Because I'm going to display Tab1 and Tab2 on a Tablet for Raspberry Pi, and we do not have keyboards, so we have to use our fingers to insert values into the tablet.
Therefore, I changed the Entry box to a label and use two buttons "+" and "-" to increment and decrement the value.
My question is, I need still to use the  tk.StringVar() for the label as you used in  self.entry_value = tk.StringVar()?

Comment: First of all, if you have found my answer useful, would you consider [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Now, this other situation you are describing is different. You would probably not need a `StringVar` anymore.

Comment: I've accepted as a good answer. I did not know how to accept the solution.
Yes, this is a new situation because now we have no keyboard and have only a touch screen.

Comment: If you are looking for an answer to your new problem, I would suggest that you write a new and separate question with the code you have written so far.

Comment: OK, I'm now trying to write my code as you suggested in OOP with a label instead of an entry. But the thing is, because of lots of widgets on both tabs, the code is going to be big. Last time I've sent 3 files for the notebook and the two tabs with only two elements on each tab, and it was complained that's too much code.
I couldn't attach these 3 files somehow.

Comment: Yes because you should only send the part that is not working and not all of your code. That's why whenever you ask a question, you are asked to only send a [example]

Comment: I've generated a new question under the subject `Where I have to put “self” in the classes for attributes and methods in python, I get errors that some attributes/methods are not defined` as you suggested in Tab_Top2 version. I hope that the code is still understandable after removing lots of parts.

Comment: Just by looking at your title, I think you are trying to do too much while understanding too little. I would suggest that you read the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) before trying to do anything else. And don't skip any pages. Good luck.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I try to go through the whole stuff. Do you have also a link for a Python tutorial with PyQt5? Because now the requirements at Work is that I have to use PyQt5 instead of Tkinter.

Comment: I haven't worked yet with Qt but a quick search yield a [tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/index.html) on the official site of Qt

Comment: Thanks for the link. I try to go through the stuff